# WPF Toolkit Source Build Not Working (after transitioning from Feb 2010 Nuget binary install)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, charts, wpftoolkit

I am been looking around and have not seen anything to solve.

Background: I am trying to rebuild from source and use the WPF Toolkit. This is to integrate in a bug fix where the chart does not update when the WPF binding source (i.e. ObservableCollection) is changed by "Insert"ing or "Clear"ing. This is key to my application working (unless someone knows of a build where these are already fixed).

Steps to Recreate:

1. Downlaoded[source from here][1]
2. Added the project to my solution, loaded it into VS 2012 Express (had to convert project up).
3. Set the .Net framework to 3.5 (since namespace ambiguities in 4.5 which are the rest of my projects in solution due to provided functionality).
4. Built WPF Toolkit and received the warning: 
   ">C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3267: The primary reference "System.Xaml", which is a framework assembly, could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v3.5". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Xaml" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Xaml"."

Why is the warning originating from framework v4.0... since this is a 3.5 project? It built so I continued (just for grins, but need to understand this warning).

5 I added the new WPF Toolkit reference to the my project. I built, verified it copied to the debug directory and ran it. Now I get the runtime exception:

"An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'WPFToolkit, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040). "

If I understand correctly, how do I change the manifest definition (if appropriate) to get this to work? This exception occurred on a dispatcher call ("BeginInvoke" or "Pushframe" ) in the main project which is framework 4.5. Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Thanks for any help! I am coming up to speed on WPF/C# and looking forward to getting this to work. Feel free to ask more details.